# Check if key/value pairs exist within array

Tags: php

I need to check if a set of query params exists within a larger set of query params. For example, I want to check if `array('option' => 'com_pages', 'view' => 'page')`, exists within:

```
Array
(
    [option] => com_pages
    [format] => html
    [view] => page
)
```

or

```
Array
(
    [option] => com_archive
)
```

I tried to find a php function that would provide this kind of search, but could't find any that matched what I was looking for. So I created the below function:

```
function checkRoute($params, $request) {
    foreach($params as $key => $value) {
        if(!array_key_exists($key, $request)) {
            return false;
        }

        if($request[$key] != $value) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Where `$request` is an array of the current request's query params.

Is there a quicker way to do this with array functions that I'm missing?

Comment: Would you expect it to return true on both of your examples? You'd like it to return true on the empty array too?

Comment: `isset( $request[$key] )` will be faster then the `array_key_exists()`, or at least it was a few years ago ... lol ... semantically I would combing the if's as well,  `if(  !isset( $request[$key] ) || $request[$key] !== $value )` and use strict typing for things like `false` vs `0` if you care about those edge cases...

Comment: You should also check [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) it gives you the intersection of your arrays

Comment: @EarthDragon - that's a good idea but I would use `array_intersect_assoc` instead so the keys are checked.

Comment: @EarthDragon, No, I'd want false on the second example. I looked at `array_intersect_assoc`, but I want to check that all the key/value pairs exist in both and that just leaves me with having to check the result, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @NicholasJohn16 what are the elements of arrays, is there any chance they are multi dimensional or they are just two one dimensional   arrays ?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Just two one-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @NicholasJohn16 I am confuse if http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMRnROX3pvOUdMdGM  will be what you want, but you may like to look into this. creating a link took 10 minutes :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an `array_intersect_assoc` for the two array and check if the count of the result is equal to the number of expected  match...

```
 if ( count(array_intersect_assoc($a, $b)) == count($a) ){
   // then match ...
 }
```

Comment: with  ..  == count($a)   much better .. thanks  .. @NicholasJohn16

Comment: As suggested by @ArtisticPhoenix you should use `array_intersect_assoc` for comparing the keys too